# FTP .txt file to a FTP site using C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a `TXT` file, and i have to `FTP` it to a `FTP site`.

I am unable to find a complete tutorial that would help me code this. Can someone please point me to a good tutorial, or a some code to start with ?

Comment: First result on google http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx, what have you tried?

Comment: Is there a way i could know if the file was uploaded successfully ?

Comment: more then checking if its there and if the sizes correspond you have few ways of checking if its correct. You could download it again and check if it has the same checksum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx) looks good to start with.

Comment: how do i know if the file was uploaded successfully ?

Comment: The thing that is confounding me is why a filename is included when setting up the FTP address:  ...WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm").  When I connect to an FTP site, I'm not looking for a specific file; I want to SEND one there.  So what is "test.htm" ?  Is that a file on the FTP site already?  Is it the file I will be sending after I send it?

My issue is when I get to the part where we go Request.GetRequestStream(), that bombs on me if I just supply my ftp address: "ftp://127.0.0.1/" saying it's not valid.  If I supply a filename I get a 550 error (file unavailable).

Comment: So I learned that the address has to be a valid URI that looks like this (minus extra spaces here):  "f t p : / / 127.0.0.1/mytestfile.txt".  If you leave off the filename it will say the Uri is not valid for that kind of operation.  The filename is what you want to call it on the remote end, it basically sets up the transfer.  The 550 errors I was getting were a result of problems with authorization, both in IIS and then at the File System level.  I was able to locate these by accessing the site using FileZilla FTP client, which shows you the conversation, which had all the clues in it.

Answer (score 3):

As I posted in the comment you can see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx) for sample of how to upload a file to a FTP server.

Code from the link:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To verify that the file was uploaded correctly, you can check the response, it has StatusDescription and a StatusCode properties.

Alternatively you call the FTP server again, where you set the method `request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;`. This will return the list of files on the FTP server.

Of course this won't verify that the file was uploaded correctly, just that there is a file by the same name.

I hope this answered your questions.

Comment: Can i print the result to the `Console` (`request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory`)

Comment: No Method is a property on the request, when you set it and get the ResponseStream you will get a list of filenames.

Comment: @Illep, take a look at this link, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/079fb811-3c55-4959-85c4-677e4b20bea3 it shows how to get a list of files on the FTP server.

Comment: But, what is the code to display all the files in the Remote FTP server ? What line in the code does it hapen ?

Comment: @Illep, look at the link it's fairly simple, the information is returned as a stream, you just have to convert it to a string. If you need more information, start a new question about this specifically, since you have already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code, applies for other file extensions too.

```
string ftpUrl = "ftp://server//foldername/fileName.ext";
string fileToUploaded = "c:/fileName.ext";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
request.Proxy = new WebProxy(); //-----Proxy bypassing(The requested FTP command is not supported when using HTTP proxy)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
                using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    using (var input = File.OpenRead(fileToBeUploaded))
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(requestStream);
                    }
                }
```

Try streaming the data, instead of loading it all into memory separately.  Also `using` statement helps to dispose the resources perfectly.